# How to aggregate related rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to group these related rows into trips (where each trip consists of a sequence from point 1->2->3->2->1).

```
route         Date        time
-------------------------------
point1      15/10/2014   9:10:10
point2      15/10/2014   10:15:00
point3      15/10/2014   10:20:00
point2      15/10/2014   11:10:00
point1      15/10/2014   12:10:00
point1      15/10/2014   12:15:00
point2      15/10/2014   13:15:10
point3      15/10/2014   14:45:00
point2      15/10/2014   15:45:00
point1      15/10/2014   16:50:00
```

I want output like this:

```
trip    Starttime   Endtime     Total
-----   ---------   --------    -----
trip1   9:10:10     12:10:00    3 hrs
trip2   12:15:00    16:30:00    4hrs 15min
```

Comment: So any time you hit a point 1, that's the end of the trip, but really the trip ended 5 minutes earlier? Why does the first trip end 5 minutes early, but not the second trip? Also 4h 15m should be 4h 35m, no? What happens if a trip straddles midnight? Is date not important in the output? What happens if the latest time is not from the end of a trip (e.g. point3)? Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: There's no `12:10:00` in your data. Where does it come from? Explain how trips are derived from points. Looks like 1,2,3,2,1 then 1,2,3,2,1 but, explain

Comment: Sorry i missed 1 row,  edited it now. I gave sample sample data only not exactly calculated data. The trip starts like 1->2->3->2->1 and again 1->2->3->2->1 and continues. I want to split by trips...Thank you

Comment: And what do you want to do if you happen to run the query in the middle of a trip? And can you correct the sample data so that the last time is 16:30 or the last total is 4hrs 35min? It's very confusing otherwise. And *one more time*: WHAT VERSION of SQL Server?

Comment: am using sql server 2008, if the trip is in the middle we will show running time up to that part

Answer (score 0):

I guess this cuts it

```
insert into trip values 
('point1',      '10/15/2014 09:10:10')
,('point2',      '10/15/2014 10:15:00')
,('point3',      '10/15/2014 10:20:00')
,('point2',      '10/15/2014 11:10:00')
,('point1',      '10/15/2014 12:10:00')
,('point1',      '10/15/2014 12:15:00')
,('point2',      '10/15/2014 13:15:10')
,('point3',      '10/15/2014 14:45:00')
,('point2',      '10/15/2014 15:45:00')
,('point1',      '10/15/2014 16:50:00')

with a as (select a.route,a.data from trip a)

SELECT 
    a.[route], 
    a.data as start,
    t.data as [end],
    total = datediff(hour, a.data,t.data)
from 
    a
join trip t on (a.route=t.route)
where a.data <> t.data 
option (maxrecursion 1)
```